# Detect user delete in Active Directory

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

Is there a way (service, app, etc) to detect when an user is disabled or deleted from Active Directory ?, something like PasswordHook, which is used to detect when an user is changing his password ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using an LDAPQuery Tool like ADInfo http://www.cjwdev.co.uk/Software/ADReportingTool/Info.html